# Create Azure-DB runs in Timeout

Tags: vb.net, azure-sql-database

I use the following code in Visual Basic.net for creating a new MS Azure-DB:

```
Dim CONNmaster As New SqlConnection("Server=tcp:blablabla.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=master;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=[myuserid];Password=[mypassword];MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=300;")
CONNmaster.Open()
SQL = "CREATE DATABASE abc123;"
Dim CMD As New SqlCommand(SQL, CONNmaster)
CMD.ExecuteScalar()
CONNmaster.Close()
```

An error is thrown:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Das Ausführungstimeout ist abgelaufen. Der Timeoutzeitraum wurde überschritten, bevor der Vorgang beendet wurde, oder der Server antwortet nicht.
CREATE DATABASE operation failed. Internal service error.'

When I exchange SQL with

```
SQL = "CREATE DATABASE [abc123]  (EDITION = 'GeneralPurpose', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'GP_S_Gen5_1', MAXSIZE = 32 GB) WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;"
```

the error stays the same (I create the script using SQL Server Management Studio: existing DB -> create create script).

The Database seems to be created correctly... I can see it in SSMS and can work with it, but the create-command above throws the runtime error (timeout).

What am I doing wrong? I have to create several empty databases using my vb.net program to create some tables in them later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, this seems do be not a timeout in the connectionstring, but in the sqlcommand, isn't it?

Adding a

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = 300
```

seems to do the trick - even the timeout occured after aprox. 10 seconds and not after 30 seconds as 30 is the default of the command.